# Hide the Cookie Banner on certain pages

Tags: magento2, cms, cookie, external, iframe

I have a product widget page which I put in an iframe of an external site.
I need to deactivate the cookie message for this, suggestions?
[image]

Comment: <style>
.cookie-bar.shown {
    display: none;
}
</style>